# Efficient way to add multiple times a 2D vector to another 2D vector

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm trying to add multiple times a 2D vector to another 2D vector.
So I have a `matrix` that is filled multiple times with `matrix2`, but more `matrix` grows, more is the time that `matrix2` takes to be added to `matrix`.

This is my actual code:

```
import numpy as np


# dummy function just for testing
def get_max_subtree_length(groups):
    return 20

def pad_groups(dataset, groups):
    dataset = np.array(dataset)
    max_subtree_length = get_max_subtree_length(groups)
    padded_dataset = np.array([[]])
    start_range = 0
    dataset_row_length = len(dataset[0]) - 1
    zeros_pad = np.zeros(dataset_row_length)
    for group in groups:
        pad = np.array([group[0]])
        pad = np.append(pad, zeros_pad)
        end_range = start_range + group[1]
        subtree = dataset[start_range:end_range, :]
        if len(padded_dataset[0]) == 0:
            padded_dataset = subtree
        else:
            padded_dataset = np.vstack([padded_dataset, subtree])
        subtree_length = group[1]
        subtree_to_pad = max_subtree_length - subtree_length
        # Append subtree_to_pad (number of pad to append) times the same pad array to the dataset
        pads = np.repeat([pad], subtree_to_pad, axis=0)
        padded_dataset = np.vstack([padded_dataset, pads])
        start_range = end_range
    return padded_dataset
```

To test it:

```
dataset = np.array([
    [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [2, 2, 3], [2, 2, 3],
    [2, 2, 3], [3, 2, 3], [3, 2, 3], [3, 2, 3], [4, 2, 3],
    [4, 2, 3], [4, 2, 3], [5, 2, 3], [5, 2, 3], [5, 2, 3],
    [6, 2, 3], [6, 2, 3], [6, 2, 3], [7, 2, 3], [7, 2, 3],
    [7, 2, 3], [8, 2, 3], [8, 2, 3], [8, 2, 3]])

groups = [(1, 3), (2, 3), (3, 3), (4, 3), (5, 3), (6, 3), (7, 3), (8, 3)]

dataset = pad_groups(dataset, groups)
print(len(dataset))
# 160
print(dataset)
# [[1. 2. 3.]
#  [1. 2. 3.]
#  [1. 2. 3.]
#  [1. 0. 0.]
#  [1. 0. 0.]
#  [1. 0. 0.]
#  [1. 0. 0.]
#  [1. 0. 0.]
#  [1. 0. 0.]
#  [1. 0. 0.]
#  [1. 0. 0.]
#  [1. 0. 0.]
#  [1. 0. 0.]
#  [1. 0. 0.]
#  [1. 0. 0.]
#  [1. 0. 0.]
#  [1. 0. 0.]
#  [1. 0. 0.]
#  [1. 0. 0.]
#  [1. 0. 0.]
#  [2. 2. 3.]
#  [2. 2. 3.]
#  [2. 2. 3.]
#  [2. 0. 0.]
#  [2. 0. 0.]
#  [2. 0. 0.]
#  [2. 0. 0.]
#  [2. 0. 0.]
#  [2. 0. 0.]
#  [2. 0. 0.]
#  [2. 0. 0.]
#  [2. 0. 0.]
#  [2. 0. 0.]
#  [2. 0. 0.]
#  [2. 0. 0.]
#  [2. 0. 0.]
#  [2. 0. 0.]
#  [2. 0. 0.]
#  [2. 0. 0.]
#  [2. 0. 0.]
#  [3. 2. 3.]
#  [3. 2. 3.]
#  [3. 2. 3.]
#  [3. 0. 0.]
#  [3. 0. 0.]
#  [3. 0. 0.]
#  [3. 0. 0.]
#  [3. 0. 0.]
#  [3. 0. 0.]
#  [3. 0. 0.]
#  [3. 0. 0.]
#  [3. 0. 0.]
#  [3. 0. 0.]
#  [3. 0. 0.]
#  [3. 0. 0.]
#  [3. 0. 0.]
#  [3. 0. 0.]
#  [3. 0. 0.]
#  [3. 0. 0.]
#  [3. 0. 0.]
#  [4. 2. 3.]
#  [4. 2. 3.]
#  [4. 2. 3.]
#  [4. 0. 0.]
#  [4. 0. 0.]
#  [4. 0. 0.]
#  [4. 0. 0.]
#  [4. 0. 0.]
#  [4. 0. 0.]
#  [4. 0. 0.]
#  [4. 0. 0.]
#  [4. 0. 0.]
#  [4. 0. 0.]
#  [4. 0. 0.]
#  [4. 0. 0.]
#  [4. 0. 0.]
#  [4. 0. 0.]
#  [4. 0. 0.]
#  [4. 0. 0.]
#  [4. 0. 0.]
#  [5. 2. 3.]
#  [5. 2. 3.]
#  [5. 2. 3.]
#  [5. 0. 0.]
#  [5. 0. 0.]
#  [5. 0. 0.]
#  [5. 0. 0.]
#  [5. 0. 0.]
#  [5. 0. 0.]
#  [5. 0. 0.]
#  [5. 0. 0.]
#  [5. 0. 0.]
#  [5. 0. 0.]
#  [5. 0. 0.]
#  [5. 0. 0.]
#  [5. 0. 0.]
#  [5. 0. 0.]
#  [5. 0. 0.]
#  [5. 0. 0.]
#  [5. 0. 0.]
#  [6. 2. 3.]
#  [6. 2. 3.]
#  [6. 2. 3.]
#  [6. 0. 0.]
#  [6. 0. 0.]
#  [6. 0. 0.]
#  [6. 0. 0.]
#  [6. 0. 0.]
#  [6. 0. 0.]
#  [6. 0. 0.]
#  [6. 0. 0.]
#  [6. 0. 0.]
#  [6. 0. 0.]
#  [6. 0. 0.]
#  [6. 0. 0.]
#  [6. 0. 0.]
#  [6. 0. 0.]
#  [6. 0. 0.]
#  [6. 0. 0.]
#  [6. 0. 0.]
#  [7. 2. 3.]
#  [7. 2. 3.]
#  [7. 2. 3.]
#  [7. 0. 0.]
#  [7. 0. 0.]
#  [7. 0. 0.]
#  [7. 0. 0.]
#  [7. 0. 0.]
#  [7. 0. 0.]
#  [7. 0. 0.]
#  [7. 0. 0.]
#  [7. 0. 0.]
#  [7. 0. 0.]
#  [7. 0. 0.]
#  [7. 0. 0.]
#  [7. 0. 0.]
#  [7. 0. 0.]
#  [7. 0. 0.]
#  [7. 0. 0.]
#  [7. 0. 0.]
#  [8. 2. 3.]
#  [8. 2. 3.]
#  [8. 2. 3.]
#  [8. 0. 0.]
#  [8. 0. 0.]
#  [8. 0. 0.]
#  [8. 0. 0.]
#  [8. 0. 0.]
#  [8. 0. 0.]
#  [8. 0. 0.]
#  [8. 0. 0.]
#  [8. 0. 0.]
#  [8. 0. 0.]
#  [8. 0. 0.]
#  [8. 0. 0.]
#  [8. 0. 0.]
#  [8. 0. 0.]
#  [8. 0. 0.]
#  [8. 0. 0.]
#  [8. 0. 0.]]
```

In this case, `matrix` is `padded_dataset` and `matrix2` is `pads`.

`groups` is 122,000 long.

**UPDATE**:

IDE to simulate the function: https://repl.it/repls/IdealKeyModes

How could I do this operation in a more efficient way?

Comment: Would you please provide the full code (I read a `return` but no `def ...`) as well as some *test* input / output?

Comment: @norok2 I provided the full function code. At this state, this function works, but it slow at a certain point.

Comment: Not really. Try copy-pasting your code in a fresh interpreter and run your function and you will understand what is missing. Also, some test input / output is missing. Are we supposed to guess what `dataset` and `groups` are?

Comment: I'm currently running this function on google colab and it works. `dataset` is a matrix of numerical vectors, `groups` it a list of couples, where the first element of the couple is an identifier for `dataset` 's batch and the second element tells me how long is that batch.
What I have to do is to pad each batch to a fixed length equal to `max_subtree_length`.

Comment: If you deem that all the code needed is already posted, please remove the noise from it (all the code that is not necessary to illustrate your problem). See also https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @norok2 yeah, I posted a link to an IDE with all the necessary (I think). Keep in mind that `dataset` initial shape is `(453000, 839)` and `groups` is long 122000, so with the reduced data in the IDE, the function is fast.

Comment: List append is much better when used a loip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could think of replacing `np.vstack()`, `np.append()` and similar with the respective `list` operations and convert the final result to `np.array()` at the end. The final result could look something like:

```
def pad_groups_opt(dataset, groups):
    dataset = np.array(dataset)
    max_subtree_length = get_max_subtree_length(groups)
    start = 0
    rows, cols = dataset.shape
    padded_dataset = []
    for group in groups:
        pad = [group[0]] + [0] * (cols - 1)
        stop = start + group[1]
        subtree = dataset[start:stop].tolist()
        padded_dataset.extend(subtree)
        subtree_to_pad = max_subtree_length - group[1]
        pads = [pad] * subtree_to_pad
        padded_dataset.extend(pads)
        start = stop
    return np.array(padded_dataset)
```

and testing it against your original code:

```
dataset = np.array([
    [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [2, 2, 3], [2, 2, 3],
    [2, 2, 3], [3, 2, 3], [3, 2, 3], [3, 2, 3], [4, 2, 3],
    [4, 2, 3], [4, 2, 3], [5, 2, 3], [5, 2, 3], [5, 2, 3],
    [6, 2, 3], [6, 2, 3], [6, 2, 3], [7, 2, 3], [7, 2, 3],
    [7, 2, 3], [8, 2, 3], [8, 2, 3], [8, 2, 3]])
groups = [(1, 3), (2, 3), (3, 3), (4, 3), (5, 3), (6, 3), (7, 3), (8, 3)]

print(np.all(pad_groups(dataset, groups) == pad_groups_opt(dataset, groups)))
# True
```

Timewise, you get some ~2x speed-up with the input:

```
%timeit pad_groups(dataset, groups)
# 10000 loops, best of 3: 169 µs per loop
%timeit pad_groups_opt(dataset, groups)
# 10000 loops, best of 3: 89.3 µs per loop
```

and seems to get even better (~10x) for larger inputs:

```
%timeit pad_groups(dataset.tolist() * 100, groups * 100)
# 10 loops, best of 3: 107 ms per loop
%timeit pad_groups_opt(dataset.tolist() * 100, groups * 100)
# 100 loops, best of 3: 9.21 ms per loop
```

Comment: Thank you, very fast. Unfortunately, the ram fills up all. Maybe I have to reduce number of groups.

Comment: If you can avoid the conversion from/to NumPy arrays, that would save you some memory. Also, perhaps you can think of rewriting the code as a generator, if you need to consume the result "line by line"

Comment: I'm padding the dataset to put it into an LSTM. What do you mean with "code as generator" ?

Comment: using `yield` instead of `return`, perhaps you could read through https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators Anyway I do not think you can do that easily if that is the input of an LSTM.